# Laravel composer is different at PROD

Tags: laravel, pusher, laratrust

My app is running ok at DEV but in production, the command `composer update` is running on an error as follows:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
    - mpdf/mpdf[v7.1.0, ..., v7.1.6] require php ^5.6 || ~7.0.0 || ~7.1.0 || ~7.2.0 -> your php version (7.4.28) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - mpdf/mpdf[v7.1.7, ..., v7.1.9] require php ^5.6 || ~7.0.0 || ~7.1.0 || ~7.2.0 || ~7.3.0 -> your php version (7.4.28) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Root composer.json requires mpdf/mpdf ^7.1 -> satisfiable by mpdf/mpdf[v7.1.0, ..., v7.1.9].
```

So I run the command `sudo composer require mpdf/mpdf` and the result is another error:

```
Problem 1
- Root composer.json requires pusher/pusher-php-server ~3.0, found pusher/pusher-php-server[3.0.0, ..., v3.4.1] but the package is fixed to v4.1.5 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
Problem 2
- Root composer.json requires santigarcor/laratrust 5.0.*, found santigarcor/laratrust[5.0.0, ..., 5.0.x-dev] but the package is fixed to 4.0.5 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command
```

Well, I did update the Laratrust to version 5, but didn't do anything at pusher… So why is that error?

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Your php version does not match between your prod env and your dev env, check what php version your app support, and be sure to be on the right version on the server, i guess your app only support php 7.2 maximum and not higher

Comment: Yes, it is different indeed: PROD is ```PHP 7.4.28``` and in DEV is ```PHP 7.3.33```. This could be the problem?

Comment: Yes if you have some packages that does not support php 7.4, try to remove the composer.lock, i guess it forces composer to install php 7.3 packages that do not work for php 7.4 and it causes that error. It's not a good idea to push/commit the composer.lock usually

Comment: One option would be to set the platform version in your composer file https://andy-carter.com/blog/composer-php-platform. I'd also recommend using the same PHP version for dev and production so you don't run into issues like this.
Lastly, I'll caveat the comment above by saying it's not usually a good idea to include a `composer.lock` file for package development. If it's for an application e.g. a Laravel project, then it's definitely recommended.

Comment: I'd disagree with @Lk77.  Definitely recommend commiting composer.lock and then ONLY running `composer install` on the production server.  This way you get the versions of the packages that you have tested with.

Comment: well you keep the same composer.lock between the tests and the prod env has i see it. I use docker so it's a little bit different, but i build an image, then i test that image and push it to production, so there is nothing different between prod and test env. You can only keep the composer.lock if you are sure of the environments your app will be deployed on

Comment: AWESOME You guys! Thanks a lot! I solve the problem with Docker. Now all my environments are the same!